# Константный объект С#

Tags: c#

```
void test(in A a) {
    a.modify(); // Не константный метод. Вызови ошибку! Нет...
}

A a = new A(1, 2);

test(a);
Console.WriteLine($"a.a: {a.a}");

public class A {
    public int a;
    public int b;

    public A(int a, int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; } // можно красивее, но пока не умею )

    public void modify() => a = b;
}
```

Как мне защитить себя от вызова для константного объекта неконстантного метода?

Comment: Покройте modify как private или protected

Comment: @Kalmankantaja тогда не смогу использовать метод вне класса когда объект НЕ константный..

Comment: В общем видимо этого никак не сделать (

Comment: Вы определитесь нужно вам изменять или не нужно. Можете использовать `record` вместо `class` и тогда единственный способ будет сделать то, что выхотите - это скопировать `record` в новый объект с измененными полями, а старые поля в старом объекте останутся неизменными

Comment: Хочу как в C++
"У константных объектов нельзя вызывать неконстантные методы"

Comment: сделайте `readonly struct` вместо класса, а вообще, чем вам не подходят обычные `readonly` поля?

Comment: Тогда не будет работать метод modify()

Comment: Что такое «константный объект»?

Comment: если вам нужен неизменяемый объект (например, как строка - она неизменяемая в дотнете), то пишите ваш класс в неизменяемом стиле - то есть любая операция изменения просто создает новый объект, а все поля закрыты для изменения извне.

Comment: а понятий "константного объекта" и "константного метода" в сишарпе я не припомню, скорее всего это что то из мира плюсов.

Comment: Полагаю, суть вопроса в [in parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier)? Это совсем не то, что модификатор параметра `const` в C++.

Comment: ^ параметр in говорит о том, можно ли менять переменную, куда записана ссылка на объект. Но не запрещает менять сам объект

Comment: @tym32167 понял, а есть какая-то альтернатива in, чтобы задать этот самый запрет на изменение объекта? (const нельзя...)

Comment: не, если у объекта есть метод, что меняет его состояние, и есть ссылка на объект, то этот метод никто не запретит вызвать. Вы можете только либо обернуть объект в ридонли обертку, типа враппер написать для него или ридонли интерфейс

Answer (score 1):

Средствами компилятора вы не можете изменяемый объект превратить в неизменяемый.

Но вы можете это сделать средствами ООП. Например, объявить интерфейс только для чтения

```
public interface IMyObjectReadonly
{
    int A{get;}
    int B{get;}
}

public class MyObject : IMyObjectReadonly
{
    public int A {get; private set;}
    public int B {get; private set;}
    
    public void SetA(int a) => A = a;
    public void SetB(int b) => B = b;
}

void Foo(IMyObjectReadonly ob)
{
    ob.SetA(10); // Error
}
```

Вы тут можете возразить, что вообще что никто не мешает `ob` кастануть в `MyObject` и вызвать что надо, типа `((MyObject)ob).SetA(10);` - и, конечно, кто так делает, будет сам себе злобным буратиной. Но если и от этого надо защищаться, то можно написать враппер, например

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int A {get; private set;}
    public int B {get; private set;}
    
    public void SetA(int a) => A = a;
    public void SetB(int b) => B = b;
    
    public IMyObjectReadonly AsReadonly() => new MyObjectReadonlyWrapper(this);

    private class MyObjectReadonlyWrapper : IMyObjectReadonly
    {
        private MyObject inner;
        public MyObjectReadonlyWrapper(MyObject inner)
        {
            this.inner = inner;
        }
        
        public int A => inner.A;
        public int B => inner.B;
    }
}
```

И вызывать метод Foo как то так

```
var myOb = new MyObject();
Foo(myOb.AsReadonly());
```

В этом случае никакие касты никуда не помогут. Единственным вариантом достучаться до объекта будет рефлексия - а это уже не просто злобное буратинство, это уже стрельба по ногам :)